# How to override computed property of protocol extension in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-extensions, computed-properties

I want to implement a theming in a way, that a feature can add its needed colors to a Theme protocol, so that any actual theme implementation must provide colors for every feature. I also want to have the theme implementation and feature theme requirements in separate files. I don't want to remove lines of code manually, if I move either theming or feature into another project.

```
import UIKit

protocol Theme {
    static var genericColor: UIColor { get }
}

protocol FeatureTheme {
    static var featureColor: UIColor { get }
}

extension Theme {
    static var feature: FeatureTheme.Type! {
        return nil
    }
}

struct LightTheme: Theme {
    static var genericColor: UIColor { return .white }

    static var feature: FeatureTheme.Type! { return Feature.self }
    struct Feature: FeatureTheme {
        static var featureColor: UIColor { return UIColor.red }
    }
}

let currentTheme: Theme.Type = LightTheme.self

print(currentTheme) // LightTheme
print(currentTheme.feature.featureColor) // error, because feature is nil
```

So, I wanted to add the FeatureTheme requirement to the Theme protocol via extension. Swift wants to see a default implementation in a protocol extension. I wanted to 'override' it in the actual LightTheme implementation, but that does not work. The property still returns nil. How can I solve this?

Comment: Static property just cannot be overridden.

Comment: @usako_lynn There is no issue of static in this case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done is correct but if you observe your code

```
let currentTheme: Theme.Type = LightTheme.self
```

`currentTheme` is type of `Theme` however you have assigned `LightTheme` which is now `Theme` and in your protocol

```
extension Theme {
    static var feature: FeatureTheme.Type! {
        return nil
    }
}
```

You have `nil` returned as default implementation which is executing because `currentTheme` is `Theme` Type not `LightTheme` and it is not required properly as well

With current implementation Solution is simple again is to declare `currentTheme` as `LightTheme`    See below answer

```
let currentTheme: LightTheme.Type = LightTheme.self
```

OR

Keep `currentTheme` to simply assign `LightTheme`  Like below

```
let currentTheme  = LightTheme.self
```

Hope it is helpful to you

> Output :
>
> LightTheme
> UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1

Comment: That actually helped me understand, why the code executes like it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The extension of `Theme` does not add any requirements to the protocol, it just adds a computed static property to anything of type `Theme.Type`. You therefore don't override the default implementation of `feature` for anything that is a `Theme.Type`. That would only be the case if `feature` were an actual requirement of the protocol. Maybe something like this:

```
protocol Theme {
    static var feature: FeatureTheme.Type { get }
    static var genericColor: UIColor { get }
}

protocol FeatureTheme {
    static var featureColor: UIColor { get }
}

struct LightTheme: Theme {
    static var genericColor: UIColor { return .white }

    static var feature: FeatureTheme.Type { return Feature.self }
    struct Feature: FeatureTheme {
        static var featureColor: UIColor { return UIColor.red }
    }
}

let currentTheme: Theme.Type = LightTheme.self

print(currentTheme) // "LightTheme"
print(currentTheme.feature.featureColor) // "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1"
```

Then there would also be no need for `feature` to be optional and force unwrapped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to avoid adding requirements of features into the file, where Theme is implemented. But it seems, there is no other possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for misunderstand in comments.
Here are two solutions:
1. It's @Prashant Tukadiya 's answer. Declare `currentTheme` as `LightTheme`.
2. I think, however, you need to make it have to be `Theme.type` for some reason. So declare `feature` as `Theme` protocol's property that can(should) be overridden.

```
protocol Theme {
    static var genericColor: UIColor { get }
    static var feature: FeatureTheme.Type! { get }
}
```

If you didn't do this, the definition of `Theme.feature` is just a static property of `Theme`. Then `LightTheme.feature` isn't inherited from `Theme` . And If you did this, `Theme.feature` can(should) be implemented in subclass. You defined a default implementation in `Theme`'s extension and can also override it.